# MutationObserver fire only at first change

Tags: javascript

In the following code, by repeatedly clicking the 2 buttons, the `observer` only fire for the first change on each observed target? (*The output show the change.*)

How do I make it fire on every change?

```js
var cc = 1;

document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  var target1 = document.querySelector('.icon-inbox .unread-count');
  target1.innerHTML = ' inbox ' + cc++;
});
document.querySelector('.button.nr2').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  var target2 = document.querySelector('.icon-achievements .unread-count');
  target2.innerHTML = ' reps ' + cc++;
});


(function(title,inbox_counter,reps_counter,inbox_value,reps_value) {
  
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

            if (mutation.type.toLowerCase() == 'attributes' && window.getComputedStyle(mutation.target,null).getPropertyValue("display") == 'none') {
                if ((' ' + mutation.target.parentElement.className + ' ').indexOf(' icon-inbox ') > -1) {
                    inbox_value  = '';
                } else {
                    reps_value = '';
                }
            } else {
                if ((' ' + mutation.target.parentElement.className + ' ').indexOf(' icon-inbox ') > -1) {
                    inbox_value  = '(' + mutation.target.textContent + ') ';
                } else {
                    reps_value = '(' + mutation.target.textContent + ') ';
                }                
            }
            
            document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = inbox_value + reps_value + title;
            
        });
    });
  
    observer.observe(inbox_counter, { attributes: true, childList: true,  }); 
    observer.observe(reps_counter, { attributes: true, childList: true,  }); 

})(document.title,document.querySelector('.icon-inbox .unread-count'),document.querySelector('.icon-achievements .unread-count'),'','');
```

```css
.button {
  border: 1px solid;
}
div {
  height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar-icon icon-inbox"><span class="unread-count"></span></div>
<div class="topbar-icon icon-achievements"><span class="unread-count"></span></div>

<br><span class="button">BUTTON</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="button nr2">BUTTON 2</span>

<br><br>Output: <span class="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In options you need to add two flags characterdata and subtree

```
    observer.observe(inbox_counter, { attributes: true, childList: true,characterData:true, subtree:true }); 
    observer.observe(reps_counter, { attributes: true, childList: true,characterData:true , subtree:true });
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Do you know why all those options need to be there?

Comment: @LGSon  I think whats happening is childList:true only detects addition and deletion of nodes. After subsequent click there is no addition only change of value is happening. so childList:true is useless and characterData:true need to be there. subtree:true need to  be true because change is happening to inner text-nodes.

Comment: Thanks, +1, and it sounds reasonable, since after the first change, the parent element became same as target, most likely because the text itself appears to be treated as a new child node.